# Problema con sweetalert confirmar enlace

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Buenos días,

Estoy algo confuso ya que he intentado realizar un modal de confirmación antes de ir a un enlace (básicamente para antes de eliminar un item de la BD, que pregunte si esta seguro) usando sweetalert2 y me surgen varios errores que no consigo/sé solucionar.

Este es el código

```
  <a id="confirm" href="http://google.com">Visit Google!</a>

  <script>
  $("#confirm").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
    var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
    warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);
  });

  function warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL) {
    swal({
      title: "Leave this site?", 
      text: "If you click 'OK', you will be redirected to " + linkURL, 
      type: "warning",
      buttons: true
    }).then( function() {
      window.location.href = linkURL;
    });
  }
  </script>
```

Con este código, si le das a cancelar cuando aparece el modal, aún así sigue llevándote a la página. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Por otro lado, no llego a entender otro concepto algo raro. Si pongo la id confirm en otro lado, exactamente en este código:

```
<ul class="page-breadcrumb">
<li> <a id="confirm" href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>dashboard">Inicio</a> <i class="fa fa-circle"></i> </li>
<li> <span>Usuarios</span> </li>
</ul>
```

No llega a funcionar el confirm, ni a mostrar el modal ni nada, va al enlace directamente.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

**---------------------------------**

Después de usar el código de las respuesta, sigo teniendo un problema al cual no le encuentro el sentido:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>profile?user=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ver Perfil </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php if($u['Activacion'] == 1): ?>
        <a href="../assets/controllers/users.php?action=desactivaruser&userid=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true"></i> Desactivar </a>
        <?php elseif($u['Activacion'] == 0): ?>
        <a href="../assets/controllers/users.php?action=activaruser&userid=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on" aria-hidden="true"></i> Activar </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Editar </a>
    </li>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#confirmBTN").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);
});
function warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL) {
swal({
title: "¿Estas segur<?php get_Genero($_SESSION['CBSGenero']); ?>?",
text: "Una vez borrado el usuario, no podrá ser recuperado.",
type: "warning",
showCancelButton: true,
}).then(function(result) {
console.log(result);
if (result.value) {
window.location.href = linkURL;
}
});
}
</script>

    <li>
        <a id="confirmBTN" href="../assets/controllers/users.php?action=eliminaruser&userid=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Eliminar </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Permisos</li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ver o Editar </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Este es el código. Cuando le doy al boton de "eliminar" no muestra la pantalla de confirmación, solo va al enlace directamente. No hay más id="confirmBTN" definidos ni nada por el estilo, por lo cual debería de funcionar correctamente... He revisado el código y no veo ningun error aparente... así que estoy un poco perdido.

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando [`SweetAlert2`](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/), veo 2 problemas:

- La propiedad `buttons` esta deprecada. En su lugar deberías usar `showCancelButton`
- No estas validando el `result.value` en la función `then`. Si `result.value` es `true`, solo entonces deberías redireccionar al link.

Demo:

```js
$("#confirm").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
  var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
  warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);
});

function warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL) {
  swal({
    title: "Leave this site?",
    text: "If you click 'OK', you will be redirected to " + linkURL,
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
  }).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.value) {
      window.location.href = linkURL;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.0.9/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<a id="confirm" href="https://google.com">Visit Google!</a>
```

Comment: He usado el código y funciona perfectamente, pero usandolo en el siguiente código: <li>
                 <a id="confirm" href="../assets/controllers/users.php?action=eliminaruser&userid=<?php echo $u['IDUser']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Eliminar </a>
                </li> no llega a funcionar, directamente va al enlace sin mostrar el modal, y la verdad es que no entiendo porque, ya que si con el otro <a> (<a id="confirm" href="https://google.com">Visit Google!</a>) funciona, debería de funcionar en todos...

Comment: si, eso lo sé, solo hay uno con el id confirm, pero igualmente no funciona... no entiendo mucho el porque la verdad, nunca me habia pasado... He probado en otras partes del código y tampoco...

Comment: He puesto el código completo en la pregunta para que puedas ver el código. No llega a generar el modal para confirmar la eliminación, así que estoy más perdido que un pescado en un desierto...

Comment: Lo he cambiado abajo también, y igualmente no funciona... Es por eso que no le encuentro ningún sentido

Comment: Este es el código completo (he probado y sigue sin funcionar) https://pastebin.com/NxRCKyK6

Comment: @CharlieClewer, veo dos problemas: 1. Eventualmente van a existir mas de un elemento con `id` igual a `id="confirmBTN"` ya que dicho elemento será creado para cada registro dentro de `foreach($query as $u) {`. 2. La línea `$(document).ready(function() { $('#usuarios').DataTable(); });` lo que hace es una vea terminada la carga de la página toma la `<table ` y crea un `DataTable`, es decir que todo elemento creado y con eventos, es destruido y es creado nuevamente sin los eventos. Prueba comentar dicha linea de `JS` y vas a ver que si funciona.

Comment: Comentando la linea funciona, así que como pensaba, era un despiste mio de no ver que se creaba una id="confirm" por cada registro de la tabla. ¿Cómo podría hacer para que funcionase con cada uno? es decir, usando una clase en vez de una id...

Comment: @CharlieClewer, considero que esta es otra pregunta, que si bien esta relacionada, en realidad el foco del problema es `DataTable` y no `Sweetalert2`. Te recomiendo que crees una nueva pregunta describiendo este nuevo escenario. Por otro lado, si alguna de las respuestas recibidas te sirvió y/o resolvió tu problema, considera votarla o marcara como acertada.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes una falla en la estructura de su `swal`, no estás habilitando el botón cancel, debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
$("#confirm").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
    var linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
    warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);
  });

  function warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL) {
    swal({
      title: "Leave this site?", 
      text: "If you click 'OK', you will be redirected to " + linkURL,
      showCancelButton: true,
      type: "warning"
    }, function(confirm){
      if(confirm){
        console.log('confirmado');
        window.location.href = linkURL;
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="page-breadcrumb">
  <li>
    <a id="confirm" href="https://www.google.com">Inicio</a> <i class="fa fa-circle"></i> </li>
  <li> <span>Usuarios</span> </li>
</ul>
```

**NOTA:** el snippet de SOes no permite la redirección a enlaces externos, si ejecutas en tu entorno local debería de hacer la redirección sin problemas.